# how to get the logged in user data in nuxtjs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxtjs

I'm using laravel backend and nuxtjs frontend, when I send a login request I get a response includes the logged in user informations with a token, the response looks like this:

> {"message":"success","token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNzFkYjA1MWM2MTYxMmE4YzAyNWI2YjU3N2xMzJiNzJjMjI0MzRlY2IzNzYwNTg2N2NjOWQ5ZWEwY2MiMJM3uYEiZ8GSlPlQhIctVErO2KzwXOBxifWWoM7et_qT-mgvfsk3ljwiQF9iPQw-WeekBx8J8lcmxDLESa3tfE1Re1Xk2flkcBLmiI4JN2YHh08U1U","user":{"id":1,"role_id":4587,"firstname":"Hans","lastname":"newman","email":"newman@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"phone":"89498","skype":"gdgdfg","birthdate":"2021-05-02","address":"asdfaf","postalcode":14984,"city":"jisf","country":"isfisf","status":"mfof","created_at":"2021-06-16T09:33:08.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-06-16T09:39:41.000000Z","image":"1623835988-carlsen.png","description":"sfdgg","geo_lat":5.5,"geo_lng":8.1}}

after logging in I want to redirect the user to his profile page where he can see his data, how can I get the logged in user data from this response.

Comment: [laravel-nuxt](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-nuxt) is a great project for the beginner who use laravel and nuxt, it has a full auth system which you can imitate

Comment: Could you please format it a bit better?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user details on the profile page using `this.$auth.user` which is provided by the nuxt auth module. This returns an array so you can access the actual details of the user using `this.$auth.user[0]` e.g `this.$auth.user[0].email` or `this.$auth.user[0].firstname` etc.

Also if you are using the nuxt module, you can access it using `this.$store.state.auth.user`.

Check out the nuxt auth module documentation for more info [here](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/auth/)

Answer (score -1):

presuming the variable which you are saving response data in is `response`. you can access the user data via `response.user`. for accessing any data inside user you can access them further like `response.user.id`.

**Beautified version of your response data for easier read:**

```
{
  "message":"success",
  "token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiNzFkYjA1MWM2MTYxMmE4YzAyNWI2YjU3N2xMzJiNzJjMjI0MzRlY2IzNzYwNTg2N2NjOWQ5ZWEwY2MiMJM3uYEiZ8GSlPlQhIctVErO2KzwXOBxifWWoM7et_qT-mgvfsk3ljwiQF9iPQw-WeekBx8J8lcmxDLESa3tfE1Re1Xk2flkcBLmiI4JN2YHh08U1U",
  "user":{
    "id":1,
    "role_id":4587,
    "firstname":"Hans",
    "lastname":"newman",
    "email":"newman@gmail.com",
    "email_verified_at":null,
    "phone":"89498",
    "skype":"gdgdfg",
    "birthdate":"2021-05-02",
    "address":"asdfaf",
    "postalcode":14984,
    "city":"jisf",
    "country":"isfisf",
    "status":"mfof",
    "created_at":"2021-06-16T09:33:08.000000Z",
    "updated_at":"2021-06-16T09:39:41.000000Z",
    "image":"1623835988-carlsen.png",
    "description":"sfdgg",
    "geo_lat":5.5,
    "geo_lng":8.1
  }
}
```

if you're redirecting the user, you have to save the response in store so you can use it in another page. unless you are using **Auth/Nuxt** which saves the data in `$auth`.